# MySQL. Выборка записей

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите запрос. Есть таблица

```
id |group|value
--------------
1  | 22  | 55
2  | 22  | 44
3  | 22  | 33
4  | 5   | 1
5  | 5   | 2
6  | 6   | 3
7  | 6   | 4
8  | 20  | 55
9  | 20  | 44
10 | 20  | 33
```

Как мне сделать запрос, что бы получить group-ы при условии, что существуют все поля c value 55,44,33 (не or) у этой group? Возможно это сделать одним запросом?
в примере должен вернуть 20 и 22. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `group`
FROM `table`
WHERE value IN (55,44,33)
GROUP BY `group`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 3
```

Comment: СПАСИБО!!! всю ночь промучался, оказывается все просто.

Answer (score 0):

```
select group from table where value IN (55,44,33)
```